# How to get the calculated value without libraries of string math operation on Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, math

What I am trying to is from "6+4/2-1*0" get the math answer which would be "6+2-1" then "7"

I managed to remove brackets if there were any and also the consecutives brackets removal so at the end I just have a line with basic operators. I need to do it without external libraries

Any help or suggestion would be great, thanks

Comment: If you don't what to use a library for that, then you will have to create a library for that. The first step would be to check how other libraries do that. Basically you'll have to write an interpreter that will take each of those chars decide if they are a digit or an operation and then call the apropriate functions that do the operation that you create with those digits as parameters. Btw, is that `[(6+4)/2]-(1*0)`? or `6+(4/2)-1*0`? or `6+[4/(2-1*0)]`? or .. you get the point, the brackets are there for a reason usually.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get what you are saying of the brakets and I managed to arrange the response in the order that the brakets are implemented, tha I already did

Comment: Take a look at Reverse Polish notation.

(also 6+4/2-1*0 is 8, not 7)

Comment: the brackets would actually be the most difficult part, for example wolfram|alpha assesses `6+4/2-1*0` as being equal to `8`.  Because it does `6+2-0`. But yeah, if you already have everything in the apropriate order, then you "just" need to read each char, check if it [isDigit](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-digit.html) or if it is an operation, then go through the sequence with a `when` statement or something that says to call [minus](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/minus.html) when the operator is `-` and so forth.

Comment: Do a search for "shunting yard algorithm" which is what many of these types of libraries are based on.